# How to bind celery application with Task class?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I want to override the Task class of Celery. I could override on_success and on_failure methods, but the run method is not that easy for me.I tried to use the bind method. My code is as below:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print("success")

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print("failed")

    def bind(self, app):
        return super(self.__class__, self).bind(app)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        x = kwargs.get('data', None)
        x = x**2


if __name__=="__main__":
     mytask = MyTask()
     app = Celery('mytask', backend='redis', broker='redis://localhost')
     mytask.bind(app)
     job = mytask.apply_async(data = 1)
```

but when i run the code i get the following error:

```
Received unregistered task of type None.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayandeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 559, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: None
```

I have searched a lot but I got no result. How should I register the task?

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly binding app is not necessary as celery task will auto-bind to current_app when calling apply_async.
If you would like explicitly binding, two ways available:
1. task.bind(app)
2. create Task class from app.Task. By inheriting app.Task, this app will be bound.

Your issue is not about binding. It's about task registry. Correct it as below:

```
from celery import Celery, Task

class MyTask(Task):
    name = 'mytask'

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print("success")

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print("failed")

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        x = kwargs.get('data', None)
        print(x**2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Celery('mytask', backend='redis', broker='redis://localhost')
    MyTask.bind(app)
    app.tasks.register(MyTask)
    app.worker_main()
```

Hope it helpful.